# Possible to inject a complete module in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to inject a complete module into a controller instead of injecting separately each services?

For example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.core']);

angular.module('myApp.core', [])
  .factory('ABService', function() {
    return {
      getA: function() {
        return 'A';
      },
      getB: function() {
        return 'B';
      }
    }
  })
  .factory('AnotherService', function() {
    return {
      calc: function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
      }
    }
  })


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, 'myApp.core') {
    ABService.getA();
    AnotherService.calc(2, 2);
});
```

Instead of

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, ABService, AnotherService) {
        ABService.getA();
        AnotherService.calc(2, 2);
    });
```

Comment: Sorry but it does not make any sense, even if it is possible (which it is not) it is going to make it difficult to test.. and you are not just injecting just only what you need. `myApp.core` is a module.. which is the container for its entities. Also read about Dependency Inversion one of the solid principles...

Comment: Imagine yourself as the JavaScript runtime. What is ABService? Where is this variable declared?

Comment: I don't understand why you say it does not make any sense.
If you are using all services in one module, it would be more efficient to inject the whole module instead of :
['$scope', 'Service1', 'Service2', 'Service3', 'Service4', function($scope, Service1, Service2, Service3, Service4) { ... }]

Answer (score 0):

No.

> Why?

You can't inject module to a controller, lets look at this image:
[image: Angular: How does it work]

What we can see from this: is that a **module** is a sort of component it self, which is built on top of controllers, directives, services and filters, and so on.

The real questions coming out of this:

**Can a module be without a controller?**

> Yes.
>   The is no necessity for a controller in a module. it pretty much depends on the job of that module, it could totally be made out of services and directives.

**Can we inject a service from a module to another module's controller?**

> Yes.
>   You totally can, this practice is usually being used when you are trying to build a **Store** site but could happen in much more cases.

You would probably have the module that contains: browsing the items, searching through items, and so on.

> But how would you create the **cart** in that manner?

Let's see: the cart looks like a component to me.

> Why?

Because it is something that I would want to test separately from the rest of the code, 
It's also built like a component that should have it's own unique services, and directives, and from my point of view should be derived from the rest of the application.

> So we should build a **module!**

Exactly, and whenever you are trying to **USE** the cart from the store's module's controller, you could simply inject the service that helped you build the cart from that module, and you could apply rules to the store's controller.

In terms of your question:
What I think you are trying to do, or atleast what is possible to do in your situation:

To inject a service from module `a` into a controller located in module `b`, there is no need to "inject" the full module into the controller, it doesn't quite make sense.

I hope I explained it as good as it sounds in my head :).

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could wrap your services into one "God" service if you really wanted to (I personally wouldn't recommend it)

```
angular.module('myApp.core', [])
  .factory('ABService', function() {
    return {
      getA: function() {
        return 'A';
      },
      getB: function() {
        return 'B';
      }
    }
  })
  .factory('AnotherService', function() {
    return {
      calc: function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
      }
    }
  })
  .factory('GodService', function(ABService, AnotherService) {
    return {
      ABService: ABService,
      AnotherService: AnotherService
    }
  })
```

Then you could inject the `GodService` and call `ABService` and `AnotherService` off of it.